# Telerik Export to Excel : Need to add an additional header containing HTML

Tags: header, asp.net-ajax, telerik, export-to-excel, radgrid

I am using the below code for Exporting the Telerik Grid content to Excel.
COde is as following:

```
grdDisbursementDetail.Page.Response.ClearHeaders();
                grdDisbursementDetail.Page.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Private);
                grdDisbursementDetail.ExportSettings.ExportOnlyData = true;
                grdDisbursementDetail.ExportSettings.IgnorePaging = false;
                grdDisbursementDetail.MasterTableView.HierarchyDefaultExpanded = true;
                grdDisbursementDetail.ExportSettings.OpenInNewWindow = true;
                grdDisbursementDetail.GridLines = GridLines.Both;

                //grdDisbursementDetail.PageSize = grdDisbursementDetail.PageCount;
                grdDisbursementDetail.ExportSettings.FileName = Common.GetLiteral("Report_DisbursementDetailReport_PDFExportFileName");

                //grdDisbursementDetail.MasterTableView.Columns[0].Visible = false;

               // grdDisbursementDetail.MasterTableView.DataSource = grdDisbursementDetail.Items;
                grdDisbursementDetail.MasterTableView.ExportToExcel();
```

`grdDisbursementDetail` is a **Telerik RadGrid**.
I want to add a HTML in the header of the excel. Please do let me know if there is a way to add header.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need a real page header or just some custom text in the beginning of the worksheet?

Custom text in the beginning of the sheet:

```
protected void RadGrid1_GridExporting(object source, GridExportingArgs e)
{
    if (e.ExportType == ExportType.Excel)
    {
         string customText = "your text goes here";
         e.ExportOutput = e.ExportOutput.Replace("<body>", "<body>" + customText);
    }
}
```

Custom text in the page header:

```
protected void RadGrid1_HTMLExporting(object sender, GridHTMLExportingEventArgs e)
{
    string headerText = "My header text";
    string css = String.Format("table @page {{ mso-header-data:\"{0}\"; }}", headerText);
    e.Styles.Append(css);
}
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this](http://www.telerik.com/forums/design-in-the-caption-header-of-a-grid-on-export) from telerik foruns

```
MyGrid.MasterTableView.Caption = "<span style='font-size:22pt;'>TEXT</span>"
```